# Categorize Trello boards or a way to filter them based on category or tag

Tags: trello

I have more than a dozen Trello boards and it's taking me time to get from one board to another. One solution I had was create two accounts; one for my personal boards and another for my work boards.  But the number of boards goes on whenever I get a project to work on.

Is there a way that boards can be categorized?

Comment: I'm up to four in the space of 10 days, with two prototypes already scrapped, somewhat addictive isn't it? :p

Answer (score 2):

At the time of this writing there are two ways to approach this, each with its own drawbacks.

1. No matter what type of Trello account you have, you can create multiple "Teams" and give different Boards to those teams.  Teams, in many parts of the UI, give the same effect as folders.  For instance, in the dropdown Boards list, you can collapse lists of Boards by Team.  So, if you're an individual, you could make a number of "Teams" with names like "Work," "Home Projects," "Templates," "Fun Stuff" or whatever, and your Boards would be grouped that way.  The caveat here is that if you're interested in upgrading to Business Class for all the additional functionality, you can only do this with one Team, unless you want to pay for a subscription for each one of your "folders" (and unless you have unlimited money, this would be insane).  Here's an example of this in action:

[image: Board list collapsed by team.]

2. If you *are* a Business Class user, then chances are you can't use option #1.  However, Business Class comes with a feature called Collections.  Collections are essentially a way to tag Boards.  You can view Boards by Collection on the Boards page, but the drawback here is that you don't get the same collapsing feature on the Boards dropdown that you do when creating "Teams" as a folder hack.  You can still use option #1 to simulate folders, but you'll have to forego having any Business Class features on the Boards you assign to "Teams" that aren't your Business Class Team.  One upshot here is that you can add a Board to more than one Collection.

The only way to get the best of both worlds, as of this writing, is to make a team for each "folder" and buy Business Class for each of those teams.  This is prohibitively expensive for the vast majority.  I do hope Trello implements a folder feature on the Boards list at some point.

Answer (score 0):

meh, I ran out of time editing my comment above.
Wouldn't using different organisations work as different categories for you?